# 'Escaping' multiple negations in sql

Tags: sql, grammar

I came across this odd case where I was testing unary operators in a test case, for example something like:

```
SELECT ++1
SELECT -1
SELECT +-+-++2
```

However, if you have two unary minuses in a row, it acts as a comment, so the following:

```
SELECT --1
```

Is not interpreted as `1`, but actually as an error, since it gets parsed as `SELECT ;`. Is the simple away around this to always parenthesize after any unary negation, such as:

```
SELECT ++--1
-->
SELECT ++(-(-(1)));
```

Or is there a better way to deal with that?

Comment: Parenthesising, or multiplying with -1. How did the need arise to use --1 (why not use 1)?

Comment: @tinazmu just some various fuzzing tests.

Comment: It should be sufficient to put a space between the two operators.

Comment: I have found that showing it as 'multiply by +/-1' is the most easily readable form: use -1 * -1 * a, instead of --1, it would have no performance impact because most compilers/optimisers would do the multiplication at compile time.